# Can't whitelist a kernel in jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm trying to setup jupyterhub with just one kernel. I've set this config parameter:

```
c.KernelSpecManager.whitelist = {'python2'}
```

However it doesn't take effect. I still can use both python2 and python3 kernels. Other config variables are being applied with no problem.

Is anyone else observing this?